# Paste option not appearing after setMovementMethod is called on editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I have a Recycler view with header as editText and then images.
When only editText is present paste option appears on editText. But when images are set and `setMovementMethod` is called Paste option disappears.

I have tried to `setFocussable(true)` after calling `editText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());` but still its not working.

Many post have been raised on similar issue but still no proper solution is there.

Comment: Did you find any solution for above issue? I am facing the same.